# How to extract lat and long of all points on Google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Suppose i searched for ATM's in india, How can i get the coordinates of all the points in the map...?

I found one of the solution as getting kml file and from there i can parse it...but when i added **&output=kml** to the link...i am unable to get the kml file...not even kml file option.

[URL after appending &output=kml](https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=atm%20in%20india&hl=en&ll=20.756114,76.420898&spn=23.160073,43.286133&safe=active&hq=atm&hnear=India&t=m&z=5&output=kml)

Please can any one help me in solving this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked the link you provided and I was **able** to download the KML file. I then opened the KML file in Google Earth which showed all the ATM's in India. I was then also able to find all the coordinates of each ATM.

See this screen shot-
[image]

Surprised why that wasn't possible with you..

Answer (score 0):

output=kml no longer works.  It was removed (probably because of abuse).  You can get some of the ATM's using the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/), but the results are limited to [60, returned 20 at a time](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging).